# Exponential moments and integrability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Given a probability distribution $P(x)$ for which the moments $\int x^rdP(x)$ and the exponential moment $\int e^{Rx}dP(x)$ exist for some positive integers $r$ and $R$, than is it true that

\begin{equation}
\int x^r e^{Rx}dP(x)< \infty 
\end{equation}
?
I know that the product of two Lebesgue integrable functions is not necessarily integrable but under which conditions is the above true?

Comment: No, the claim is in general not true.

Comment: But, assuming the distribution is restricted to $x\geqslant0$, every $x^se^{Sx}$ is integrable if $s\geqslant0$ and $S<R$.

Comment: Could you please detail a bit, @Did? By the way, would the finiteness of absolute moments $\int |x|^rdP(x)$ and the condition $R>1$ help in any way?

Comment: I actually don't see why you need $x$ positive and $S<R$. Could you please give a hint to this.