# Log of characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am looking at a proof related to CLT and I have difficulties understanding a condition in the theorem.

Basically, the theorem is trying to show that $\frac{d^m}{d u}ln[\varphi(u)]\leq k \beta_n $ if the absolute moment $\beta_n$ exists

**and** $u$ is such that $|\varphi(u)-1|\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

I don't understand why do I need "$u$ is such that $|\varphi(u)-1|\leq \frac{1}{2}$". The proof mentions that $ln[\varphi(u)]$ is defined for those $u$, which is the only time they use the condition. Then they go on and state that $\frac{d^m}{d u}\varphi(u)\leq E[|X^m|] $ .

I believe that this has to do with the Taylor representation of the  $ln[\varphi(u)]$ and the Taylor representation of  $\varphi(u)$ in terms of the moments but I don't understand why do I need the condition on $u$ and why $\frac{1}{2}$.

(The problem that I have seems to be related to when those Taylor expansions are valid but don't understand exactly how that works and especially why $\frac{1}{2}$. Would really appreciate a detailed answer with emphasis on this issue. Thank you.)

Comment: The condition that $|z-1|\leqslant\frac12$ ensures that $\log(z)$ is well defined and equal to its Taylor expansion around $z=1$ with well behaved remaining terms. Every condition $|z-1|\leqslant t$ would work for $t<1$.

Comment: Right, but why  $|z-1|\leq \frac{1}{2}$? Isn't Taylor expansion convergent for all $|z|<1$?

Comment: See last part of my first comment.

Comment: So, basically $\frac{1}{2}$ is arbitrary, I can take anything between 0 and 1, right?

Comment: Sorry but which part of `Every condition |z−1|⩽t would work for t<1` do you fail to get?

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, any more thoughts on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229980/exponential-moments-and-integrability?

Comment: Same answer: which part of `assuming the distribution is restricted to x⩾0, every xseSx is integrable if s⩾0 and S<R`do you fail to get?